# Find out scope for a Pinterest access_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, pinterest

I'd like to ask for write permissions using the Pinterest api only when they're required, so I'd like to query the current `access_token` and find out all the scopes that the token grants.

I can't see anything on the docs about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a currently undocumented /v1/oauth/inspect endpoint you can use. Try this.

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/inspect?access_token=<token>&client_id=<app-id>
```

If you don't need to do it programmatically, you can use the [Token Debugger](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/token-debugger/).

Comment: I replaced that second &token to be &client_id, and it works great.